# Content Access Drupal 6.28 - Doesn't work

Tags: users

We have a website which has 4 users type (excluding anonymous and authenticated). When we created a node today after we updated the version 6.28, the page access options of that content was restricted to a certain user. But when we visit as an anonymous user, the page can be seen.

I already checked the permission of each user roles and it is ok.

Hope you can help me with this problem

Comment: Module bugs should be reported in the respective module's issue queue: http://drupal.org/project/issues/content_access?categories=All

Comment: Hello Patrick, it seems maybe the problem is in the drupal or in the content_access?? because we did not updated the content but instead the drupal 6.

Comment: If you're not sure whether the bug is in Drupal or a module, file the issue in the module's issue queue first.  Drupal is much better tested than the individual modules, so it is most likely a module problem.